# WSL2 Nginx - Works on localhost but throws 403 Forbidden on 127.0.0.1 or custom host name

Tags: php, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to setup nginx on my WSL2 running Ubuntu 20.04. I got pretty much the entire site setup. It's working when I visit http://localhost. But I want it to be on http://app.test. So I added it to the host and tried, it throws 403 Forbidden error. I've not changed anything in `nginx.conf`. This is what I have so far:

**Server Block**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html/app.test;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

**Permissions**

The `/var/www/html/app.test` folder belongs to `www-data:www-data` user and group.

**Hosts**

I've added the following in both my Windows Hosts and on Ubuntu Hosts

```
127.0.0.1 app.test
```

**Findings**

1. I checked the access.log. I've included 2 of the logs below. The first one is a non-working one (when visiting app.test) and the other is a working one (when visiting localhost).

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2020:00:07:09 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 564 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;..."

::1 - - [05/Nov/2020:00:01:13 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;...
```

2. I tried running a curl command from Windows Terminal, I get 200 OK for `http://localhost` but 403 Forbidden for `http://127.0.0.1`

Thanks!

Comment: Finding 1: no, both of those requests returned status 403. Finding 2: curious (i.e., impossible), but I'm not sure how it relates to "app.test". Overall, given your setup, the request for ```http://app.test``` should result in serving ```/var/www/html/app.test/index.html```. The URL has no path component, so you're requesting ```/``` (as ```GET /``` in the access log confirms), and the index directive maps the request for a directory to a request for the index.* file(s) you specified. Just take your time and re-read the documentation. It's quite logical.

Comment: @Buster I made a mistake with finding 1, I've edited the question now. I'm guessing it's a problem with the hosts because I'm working with WSL2

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for me.

Just add:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 app.test 
::1 app.test
```

WSLUbuntu:/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 app.test
```